# cqlsh COPY TO command errors as its trying to connect to multiple nodes and failing

Tags: cassandra

I have forwarded a port to Cassandra pod and trying to back up the keyspace to CSV file. It's connecting successfully and backing up some records. However, it's trying to connect other nodes on the cluster and failing with the error given below (I have replaced the real IP with a dummy).

Can somebody please help ensure I connect to all nodes on the cluster and backup data in a single command?

command used-

```
cqlsh localhost port -u "userid" -p "pwd" -e "copy keyspace.table to data200123.csv' with header=true"

<stdin>:1:Error for (-3075426476508125267, -3075065394427965666): Failed to connect
to all replicas ['10.x.x.x'] for (-3075426476508125267, -3075065394427965666),
errors: ['NoHostAvailable - (\'Unable to connect to any servers\',
{\'10.x.x.x:port\': OSError(None, "Tried connecting to [(\'10.x.x.x\', port)].
Last error: timed out")})'] (will try again later attempt 1 of 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when doing a `COPY` on large tables before.  One thing you can try is to limit the `PAGESIZE` and set a higher `PAGETIMEOUT`.

As of Cassandra 2.2, cqlsh `COPY` uses driver-side paging to pull smaller amounts of data at a time.  `PAGESIZE` defaults to 1000, and `PAGETIMEOUT` defaults to 10 seconds.

By lowering the PAGESIZE to something a lot smaller (like 40 or 50) and doubling the allowed timeout setting for each page (like 20) you should be able to export a large table without losing a connection.

Example:

```
COPY invoices(id_invoice, year, id_client, type_invoice) 
  TO 'invoices.csv' WITH HEADER=true AND PAGETIMEOUT=40 AND PAGESIZE=20;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running into a networking issue and cqlsh (client) is unable to access nodes in your cluster.

It isn't clear based on your description how your environment is configured but since you are port-forwarding, I suspect you've either deployed Cassandra in (a) a Docker environment or (b) a Kubernetes cluster. If either is the case, basic port-forwarding won't work and you need to take additional steps to make Cassandra accessible by client applications.

#### Docker

You need to create a [Docker bridged network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) to make the nodes accessible. For example:

```
$ docker create network cassandra-network
```

Then use this network when you run the containers, for example:

```
$ docker run ... --network cassandra-network ...
```

You should then be able to connect to the Cassandra nodes on this network. For example:

```
$ docker run --rm -it 
    --network cassandra-network
    nuvo/docker-cqlsh cqlsh cassandra 9042 --cqlversion='3.4.5'
```

#### Kubernetes

You need to define a Kubernetes service that exposes the pods to clients which are outside the Kubernetes cluster.

For a working example, see the official Kubernetes docs on how to [Use a Service to Access an Application in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/). Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Erick. Yes, Cassandra is deployed on Kubernets. Tried by forwarding port from service as well. The service shows the end points of all 3 cluster nodes but the COPY command is still failing with -errors: ['NoHostAvailable - (\'Unable to connect to any servers\. Wondering what could be the potential problems.

Comment: Then it means that cqlsh can't access the cluster in Kubernetes. Cheers!